# Adding Javascript to Wordpress post body

Tags: wordpress

I am not able to add the following javascript into my wordpress post.

The javascript is provided by Google to display a map of the web search results.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2578_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("GEO_MAP", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"covid","geo":"","time":"today 12-m"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=covid&date=today 12-m","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); </script>
```

I have tried to add the javascript using the text editor (not visual) and also tried to add the javascript above within the "< code > </ code >", but it is still unsuccessful. Referring to this feedback [adding javascript in wordpress posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211492/adding-javascript-in-wordpress-posts) (which might be stale)

What should I do if I wanted to add the above javascript into the wordpress post body?

---

**Update:**
@bhanu below is how I added the Javascript which results in an empty body post.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is very simple to do that. I don't fully understand if you are on Gutenberg or classic Editor so I am going to show it for both of them.

### Execute JS inside post with Gutenberg

- Use **Custom HTML** block to and paste your code inside the block. If you are adding JS you must wrap it around `<script></script>` tag.

[image: JS in gutenberg]

- This would give the following result.

[image: output : JS in gutenberg]

---

### Execute JS inside post with Classic Editor

- If you have some content like this.

[image: js in Classic]

- Switch to text mode and paste the code where you want to add it.

[image: js in Classic - code added]

- This would be the output.

[image: js in Classic - output]

Comment: Thanks for the response. From the visual that you pasted, I am using Classic Editor. I have switched to the "Text" view, and paste the javascript codes, but the post doesn't show the map as you have shown above. Do you know whether I need to enable something before the javascript is enable to execute?

Comment: @Calvin no, can you share screenshots of how you added it and what do you see on the post page. Also is there something in the console.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how I added the Javascript.

Comment: I root caused the issue is at my side. Based on your recommendation, after adding the Javascript, I use 2 different browsers to browse the post. The issue occurs in Safari while Chrome has no issue to show the javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to add Javascript to your Wordpress site. Obviously in this case you're wanting to add it to an individual post/page, rather than site-wide. So a good option is to use the [CodeEmbed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-embed-code/#description) plugin, which has 30,000 active users, is free & open-source on SVN, and receives frequent updates.

After activating this plugin, go back to the edit post/page webpage in your admin panel, and enable "Custom Fields" in "Screen Options". Scrolling down below the content body field, you'll see a new field where you can insert js code:

[image]

After adding this field, simply add the shortcode `{{CODEmyjscode}}` anywhere in THAT SPECIFIC page/post's body field.

If you don't want to use a plugin, simply use the "Custom HTML" button in the WYSIWYG Wordpress editor and paste your jscode inside the Custom HTML area, making sure to add  tags

-L